# Facing round off issue with Jmeter Throughput Metric in exported CSV file in Jmeter 5.0

Tags: csv, jmeter, throughput

I can see the whole number for Throughput in Jmeter 5.0, if I double click against each of the sampler. 
[image]

But it doesn't appear when I export the same report in .csv file.
[image]

It is round off in the CSV file, and I need to have the whole number so that I can compare with Baseline and Prior deployments.

How to deal with it, I have been doing the same and it was/is working in older version of Jmeter 2.13, recently I upgraded to latest version 5.0 and facing this issue.

Could anyone help me out on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [Synthesis Report plugin source](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/tools/synthesis/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/vizualizers/SynthesisReportGui.java#L221)

```
new RateRenderer("#.0"), // Throughput
```

I don't see easy way of getting the full throughput number as it is being cut to one decimal number.

I would recommend going for [Summary Report Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) instead, looking into [its source](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_0/src/components/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/SummaryReport.java#L149)  you will have 5 decimal points in the resulting table.

```
new DecimalFormat("#.00000"),      // Throughput //$NON-NLS-1$
```

Also be aware that you can use [Merge Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) in order to combine results of 2 test runs into a single .jtl file and provide difference prefixes to different runs. Once done you will be able to visualize the difference in throughput for 2 test runs using i.e. [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listener

[image]

You can install Merge Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri

Yes, the Throughput number is limited to 1 decimal point in the "jp@gc - Synthesis Report (filtered)" Listener

Whereas we can still get the Throughput number upto 5 decimal point in Summary & Aggregate Report Listeners

This only happens with the latest Jmeter version along with the latest Plugins, and Plugin Manager

Answer (score 0):

The Throughput number is limited to 1 decimal point in the **jp@gc - Synthesis Report (filtered)** Listener

Whereas we can still get the Throughput number upto 5 decimal point in **Summary & Aggregate Report** Listeners

This only happens with the latest Jmeter version along with the latest Plugins, and Plugin Manager

But I needed to use only the **jp@gc - Synthesis Report (filtered)** Listener as I have to use both 90% Line Response Time and Std. Dev. metrics in my custom report, also it has the RegExp filtering capabilities which the above two in-built Listeners are not having.

Hence, have found a Workaround:
Replaced the following older Jar files manually into the latest Jmeter 5.0, and it works.

```
-JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar
-JMeterPlugins-Extras.jar
-JMeterPlugins-ExtrasLibs.jar
```

This helps me to have the whole Throughput number from the "jp@gc - Synthesis Report (filtered)" Listener